# C# DevExpress scheduler read only

Tags: c#, devexpress, scheduler

.NET4 and C#.

Created a form, used a DevExpress scheduler successfully. My form currently has a login, one type can read and write using the scheduler. But the other group I need to restrict there ability to write, basically read only.

I've tried adding a separate conn string to the "storage sched", but this actually errors saying the connection is closed (no idea what its on about since its through the wizard.)

I have no code obviously because I'm asking if there's actually a 1 line code that toggle read or write (I pray there is).

If not whats the long winded way?

Many thanks

Comment: what do you mean you can't get at the code.. can you create what you need without a Wizard..?? I am sure that the Wizard code will allow for you to alter and or assign sql query script...

Comment: originally when i did this i created the insert update query using the wizard after creating a connection string.  The problem is when i got to create another one to the same server and DBO it errors and says my connection is closed, even though it auto detects the DBO.....bit strange

Comment: Well if you can check if the Connection.State = Closed prior to what ever it is that you are doing.. do you follow..? if closed then open that connection

Comment: i understand what u mean, but the program is not running, this is simply the wizard.  I think its has something to do with the other connection string being identical but because its devexpress and inside a wizard its a nightmare to debug

Comment: you can change the connection string.. the question is do you know how or where to dynamically assign the Connection string and or change it.. do you utilize a .Config file at all...? sounds like you have a Mess going on over there.. why use a Wizard..???

Comment: because im using devexpress controls, and it would take me a long time to learn the massive api.  using the wizard allows for faster applications.  There is no mess because its all wizard based on the scheduler which is completly fine.  the problem arrises when the application changes half way through the cycle and something like this happens

Comment: if it changes then you will have to code or account for the changes if the controls that you are using do not support the changes.. this is what being a Coder / Developer is about.. sorry if you are frustrated but you will have to start somewhere...

Comment: erm im a little confused to what you mean since changes were made and documented, the problem as i said is the lack of knowledge in using dev express API.  ive managed to find where i could skip adding anew connection and instead try and turn off the insert and delete function the table-adapter has,  so far no luck gona have to look into its a little deeper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a look and it seems there are methods which you can call that restrict access.  All that needs to be done is restrict this to the users and should work.